Name of viewlayer from app_handler?
I'm trying to get the name of the current view layer in a pre render app handler, but without success. It only seems to print "ViewLayer" (first?), no matter which view layer is active. Any suggestions?
import bpy

@persistent
def get_view_layer(scene):
    print(bpy.context.view_layer.name)

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.render_init.append(get_view_layer)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.render_init.remove(get_view_layer)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    register()

